# When can karmaphal transfers from one person to another person?

Tags: karma

Can karma phala transfers from one person to another person. Some acupuncture doctors are saying that they getting pain on the particular area after treating patient. Eg.If patient has leg pain doctor also getting leg pain after treating and They told they are doing particular chinese meditation before starting work to avoid karma pala transfer. If karma phala can transfer explain with logic.

Comment: Pranic healing basically where you get karma transfer.  Because if A gives his Prana to B, B's karmas will affect you because of energy transfer.  Pranic healing will be done only be extremely advanced yogis and siddhas because they only know how to not get affected by others karmas. Even if you teach some mantras to other person without proper guidance to avoid their karma, you will also get it! More than physical diseases, karma is a big disease. Its like walking on a thin rope between one building top staris to another. Any mistake , that's it!

Comment: Karma can be easily transferred either by blessing or cursing.

Comment: Unless you're turiya, if you heal someone by spending prana like reiki or by touch like accupuressure, you're bound to, you'll get their Karma, as well as negative energy.